# Re purchasing on auto renewable subscription Error in ios

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit

I am re purchasing the subscription it's giving me this popup "You are currently subscribed" and then in UpdateTransaction observer I am getting, transaction state is Failed.
http://prntscr.com/n7tiq1
https://prnt.sc/n7ti45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior - you can't repurchase a subscription that you already own. You'll get a failure reason of `SKErrorCode = 2` which is payment cancelled: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerrorcode

Hopefully Apple can improve this in the future to just automatically restore the subscription or something and send a success response.

Comment: I'm in a sandbox environment bought a monthly auto-renewable plan in my app and it expired after 30 minutes (expected). At its expiry, I cannot purchase it again from my own app? only we can purchase from the subscription list in the sandbox account?